# I wanted to make multi-input separated by comma and I got operation error

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

```py
import math
c = 50
h = 30
d = str(input("Masukkan nilai D..."))
list = str.split (" ", )
for i in list:
    list.append(int(i))

OperasiBilangan = math.sqrt((2*c*d)/h)

print("Hasil Akhir", round(OperasiBilangan))
```

I just wanted to make a program that process variable value on d, but with more than one value separated with comma (78,12,02). How could I do it?

I'm a beginner.

Comment: you want the user to enter ```c, d, and h?```

Comment: I want the user to enter d

Comment: Then simply look up how to enter multiple integers on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```py
import math
c = 50
h = 30
d = input("Masukkan nilai D... ")

numbers = [int(i) for i in d.split(',')]
for num in numbers:
    print('D: ', num)
    print('Hasil akhir: ', round(math.sqrt((2*c*num)/h)))
```

You don't need to cast the output of `input()` to `str`. Also, don't name your variables that will collide with the standard function names because it will be overridden.

Comment: Thanks dude, that's very helpful :)